# .NET: What is that new VS feature for compiling the same project for multiple frameworks?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

A couple months ago I heard about a new Visual Studio feature for compiling the same project to multiple frameworks (e.g. .NET 4 & Silverlight). What was it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portable Library Tools

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean [Multi Targeting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx).

Comment: No. As I said in my question, this thing allowed you to compile the _same project_ to multiple frameworks. Multi-targeting just lets you pick a single framework.

Comment: @Jonathan - I have never heard of what you are looking for. The closest I can think of is having several [build configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165407.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that led me to the answer. It's called "Portable Library Tools".

Comment: @Jonathan - I see. It's not a feature of Visual Studio - it is an add-on. Guess that's what threw me off, I assumed a built in VS feature.